# Removing objects from array based on two properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5

I have an array that contains custom objects that look like this:

```
{
    field: fieldName,
    dataType: usuallyAString,
    title: titleForLocalization,
    environmentLabel: environmentName
}
```

There are a couple of other properties on the object, but the only ones that I actually care about are `field` and `environmentLabel`. I need to filter out any objects that have identical `field` and `environmentLabel` but don't care about any other properties. The array can have objects that share `field` or `environmentLabel`, just not both.

Ideally I'd like to use `Array.filter` but have yet to figure out how to do it based on two properties. Also, I am limited to es5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another object that contains all the combinations of properties you want to test. Use `filter()` and test whether the pair already exists in the object. If not, add the properties to the other object and return `true`.

```
var seen = {};
newArray = array.filter(function(obj) {
    if (seen[obj.field]) {
        if (seen[obj.field].includes(obj.environmentLabel) {
            return false;
        } else {
            seen[obj.field].push(obj.environmentLabel);
        }
    } else {
        seen[obj.field] = [obj.environmentLabel];
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I will note that it is missing a closing parenthesis on the nested `if`. I can't submit an edit that is less than 6 chars though, lol

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    field: 1,
    dataType: "usuallyAString",
    title: "titleForLocalization",
    environmentLabel: 1
},
{
    field: 1,
    dataType: "usuallyAString",
    title: "titleForLocalization",
    environmentLabel: 1
},
{
    field: 2,
    dataType: "usuallyAString",
    title: "titleForLocalization",
    environmentLabel: 2
}]

var result = _.uniqWith(data, function(arrVal, othVal) {
  return arrVal.field=== othVal.field && arrVal.environmentLabel=== othVal.environmentLabel;
});

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you are able to use lodash, you can do:

```js
var result = _.uniqWith(data, function(arrVal, othVal) {
  return arrVal.field=== othVal.field && arrVal.environmentLabel=== othVal.environmentLabel;
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I should have had it in the original question, but I am not able to use lodash or add any new dependencies into the code.